# UPS returns 3 Day Select rate quote even though there is no 3 Day Select to that destination!

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.4, ups

Why is the UPS XML rate quote, which is standard in Magento, return a rate for UPS 3 Day Select, even if there is no 3 Day Select to that destination.

Example: the ship from zip code is 99999, and the ship to zip code is 99999. So really UPS should only return rates for UPS GND and UPS Next Day Air options. There should not be a 2 day or 3 day, yet they are quoted. Why? Isn't there a way to fine tune or disabled that? Also, is there a way to get time in transit returned from UPS? When I go to the UPS Worldship website and get a rate quote it tells me exactly how many days transit UPS Ground, or UPS Standard, or UPS international options have, at least in form of 5-7 days, or 4 days, or what not. Why is this not integrated in the Magento 1.9.2.4 system.

Or is it a settings issue? My main thing is that it is displaying a UPS  3 Day Select option even though if UPS Ground has a 1 day transit time. UPS website does not give a UPS 3 Day select quote when I run the very same quote.

Anyone knows? Thanks.

Mr L

Answer (score 0):

I am still trying to wrap my head around this. So let's say I am shipping from 90505, and I am shipping to 90505. Why am I getting UPS 3 Day and 2nd Day Air as a possible shipping option in Magento 1.9.2.4? I just don't understand. When I go to the UPS website, and type in the same info into their online shipping rate calculator I only get UPS Ground and Next Day options rates. No 3day and no 2nd day. Why is Magento returning 3 Day and 2nd Day options in addition to Ground and next day?

Also, why is Magento returning time in transit for FedEx, but not for UPS? Why is the time in transit wrong in FedEx? Gives me 1 business day for Ground, and 5 business days for FedEx Express Saver. Why?

Thanks,

Martin